# fstab mounts some logical volume as /dev/dm-0 dm-1 instead as /dev/mapper/VG...

Tags: linux, debian, mount, fstab

I run Linux snore 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux, with the following fstab:

wr@snore:/etc$ cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/VG0-SLASH /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=9f0e490f-a55b-4335-8c6f-d7ef4d56a7d0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG0-HOME /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG0-OPT /opt            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG0-TMP /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG0-USR /usr            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG0-VAR /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG0-SWAP none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

however, the df command shows:

wr@snore:/etc$ df

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0              1886280    314036   1458376  18% /
udev                     10240         0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                  3287660      9644   3278016   1% /run
/dev/dm-1             23897980  13848200   8812788  62% /usr
tmpfs                  8219144    561516   7657628   7% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                  8219144         0   8219144   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1               944120     40576    838368   5% /boot
/dev/mapper/VG0-VAR    9480420   5436404   3539392  61% /var
/dev/mapper/VG0-OPT   14286320   1248128  12289444  10% /opt
/dev/mapper/VG0-TMP    9480420     22636   8953160   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VG0-HOME 480486104 249255728 206799992  55% /home
tmpfs                  1643832         8   1643824   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs                  1643832        20   1643812   1% /run/user/1000
```

where /usr and / are mapped as /dev/dm-1 and /dev/dm-0 respectivelly.

Does anybody knows why? I have no problems so far but a warning on shutdown.

Comment: To read `/etc/fstab`, `/` has to be mounted, so the initial setting must be somewhere else. Investigate `root=` kernel option in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it should be there. Honestly I don't know the full procedure, whether and when `fstab` setting replaces the initial one, but this is the first thing I would check in case of such a mismatch. I can't explain `/usr` mismatch though.

Comment: thanks for the reply but grub.cfg has the right option: linux /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/VG0-SLASH ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet